# Custom Google Maps legend filter

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've made a pretty large custom google maps code with own markers and locations which is working perfectly.

But now I've been figuring out for days how to get a custom google maps legend with active filter... but I just can't get anything to work. I used [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-legend) and many more forums. I would just like a simple `check box`/`legenda` where people can filter the different options.

This is the short version of my code.

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 420px;margin:10px 0px 30px;">
<div class="container">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 9,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.524500, -4.882175),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var Marbella = new google.maps.LatLng(37.521604, -5.046373);
    var Marbella2 = new google.maps.LatLng(37.558387, -4.929676);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: Marbella,
        url: 'marbella.html',
        title: 'Marbella',
        icon: 'images/...png',
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      window.open(this.url, '_blank');
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: Marbella2,
        url: 'marbella2.html',
        title: 'Marbella2',
        icon: 'images/...png',
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      window.open(this.url, '_blank');
    });

    var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
    for (var key in icons) {
      var type = icons[key];
      var name = type.name;
      var icon = type.icon;
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + icon + '"> ' + name;
      legend.appendChild(div);
    }

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
  }
  </script>
</div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS in the HEAD:

```
<style>
  #legend {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
  }
  #legend h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  #legend img {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

Comment: `filter the different options` - which options? filter what? I can't see your code has any "options" or "filtering"

Comment: Sorry, I've added some code to my question which is provided by google but I'm probably to new to this to figure out what I'm doing wrong.. I have marbella and marbella2 (and a lot more) and I'd like people to filter those options. So when you have 10 markers of marbella and 10 of marbella2 they would only see one of those. Is this a bit clear?